# how to get label to constantly display int (swift4)

Tags: swift, overriding, swift4, constants, var

I am wondering if there is a way to get the label to display what the int. Basically overriding all of the if statements. I know I can do this witch if statements but I am just asking this question to see if i can write more efficient code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var time = -3
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func method2() {
        time += 1
        label.text = String(time)
    }

    @IBAction func method1() {
        time += 1
        label.text = String(time)
    }
}
```

You see in this code that label.text = String(time) is repeated twice. I am trying to see if I can write this code so that it only appears once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this, you can create an additional method, like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var time = -3

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func method1() {
        self.incrementAndDisplayTime()
    }

    @IBAction func method2() {
        self.incrementAndDisplayTime()
    }

    private func incrementAndDisplayTime() {
        self.time += 1
        label.text = String(time)
    }
}
```

Or show time whenever time is set:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var time = -3 {
        didSet {
            self.label.text = String(time)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func method1() {
        self.time += 1
    }

    @IBAction func method2() {
        self.time += 1
    }

}
```

Or call one method from another:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var time = -3
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func method1() {
        self.method2()
    }

    @IBAction func method2() {
        time += 1
        label.text = String(time)
    }
}
```